# How to apply a custom stemmer before passing the training corpus to TfidfVectorizer in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, stemming, document-classification, tfidfvectorizer

Here is my code, I have a sentence and I want to tokenize and stem it before passing it to TfidfVectorizer to finally to get a tf-idf representation of the sentence:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import nltk 
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer

stemmer_ita = SnowballStemmer("italian")

def tokenizer_stemmer_ita(text):
    return [stemmer_ita.stem(word) for word in text.split()]

def sentence_tokenizer_stemmer(text):
    return " ".join([stemmer_ita.stem(word) for word in text.split()])

X_train = ['il libro è sul tavolo']

X_train = [sentence_tokenizer_stemmer(text) for text in X_train]

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(preprocessor=None, tokenizer=None, use_idf=True, stop_words=None, ngram_range=(1,2))
X_train = tfidf.fit_transform(X_train)

# let's see the features
print (tfidf.get_feature_names())
```

I get as output:

```
['il', 'il libr', 'libr', 'libr sul', 'sul', 'sul tavol', 'tavol']
```

if I change the parameter

```
tokenizer=None
```

to:

```
tokenizer=tokenizer_stemmer_ita
```

and I comment this line:

```
X_train = [sentence_tokenizer_stemmer(text) for text in X_train]
```

I expect to get the same result but the result is different:

```
['il', 'il libr', 'libr', 'libr è', 'sul', 'sul tavol', 'tavol', 'è', 'è sul']
```

Why? Am I implementing correctly the external stemmer? It seems, at least, that the stopwords ("è") are removed in the first run, even if stop_words=None.

[edit]
As suggested by Vivek, the problem seems to be the default token patter, which is applied anyway when tokenizer = None. So if a add these two lines at the beginning of tokenizer_stemmer_ita:

```
token_pattern = re.compile(u'(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b')
text = " ".join( token_pattern.findall(text) )
```

I should get the correct behaviour, and in fact I get it for the above simple example, but for a different example:

```
X_train = ['0.05%.\n\nVedete?']
```

I don't, the two outputs are different:

```
['05', '05 ved', 'ved']
```

and

```
['05', '05 vedete', 'vedete']
```

why? In this case the question mark seems to be the problem, without it the output are identical.

[edit2]
It seems I have to stem first and then apply the regex, in this case the two outputs are identical.

Comment: The current code you posted is erroneous. Please double check with your actual code.

Comment: You are right, the code is now correct and you can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because of default tokenizer pattern `token_pattern` used in TfidfVectorizer:

> token_pattern : string
>
> Regular expression denoting what constitutes a “token”, only used if analyzer == 'word'. The default regexp selects tokens of 2 or more
>   alphanumeric characters (punctuation is completely ignored and always
>   treated as a token separator).

So the character `è` is not selected.

```
import re
token_pattern = re.compile(u'(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b')
print token_pattern.findall('il libro è sul tavolo')

# Output
# ['il', 'libro', 'sul', 'tavolo']
```

This default `token_pattern` is used when tokenizer is None, as you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks Vivek, this explain most of the story, but in other cases things are still not working (probably due to how punctuation is treated), see my edit to the question.

Comment: It seems I have to stem first and then apply the regex, which seems illogical to me: I would say find the token first, then apply the stemmer, am I right?

Comment: Forget my last comment, the regex is applied after the stemmer just because I am passing the text already stemmed when tokenizer is None, so everything makes sense. Thanks again. What's the easiest way to emulate the simple text.split() defining a token_pattern?